# Exposed filter only allowing content types in list

Tags: views, 8

I have a view called (*Resources*) that displays content filtering by content type. These are the selected options:

- Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it: ✅
- Filter type to expose: **Single filter**
- Operator: **Is one of**
- Content types: **Article**, **Post**, **Story** (NOTE: I have other content types, such as *Basic Page* that shouldn't be included in this view at all)
- Allow multiple selections: ✅

However, when *none* of the options are selected, it also brings in other content types, such as *Basic Page*, which shouldn't be.

How can I make it so that when *none* of the content types in the exposed filter are selected, the results are still filtered such that the nodes must be of one of the chosen content types (Article, Post, Story)?

In other words, I would like the view to behave such that, when *none* of the content types are selected, it acts as though *all* of them are checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.

I simply added a duplicate of my "Content type" filter, except this filter *is not* exposed. Same settings as above ("Is one of", Article/Post/Story, etc.), just an extra restriction on the results to *always* filter by all of the desired content types, with the exposed filter being an *additional* option to *further* narrow down the results.